# How to remove userprofile?user=myname by htacces

Tags: .htaccess

About my question I found many more solution here stockoverflow and many others web site. But all of those htaccess rules not work for me.

I want remove `userprofile?user=` from `userprofile?user=myname`

My domain from Godaddy and hosting from onelancer
Apache Version  2.2.27
PHP Version 5.4.28

I have no idea about htaccess rule?

> my current url is like: domain.com/myfolder/userprofile?user=myname
>   Here I already hide `myfolder` from url by htaccess

My .htaccess: ( At website root )

```
### Removed myfolder ### ( Working well )
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule (.*) $1\.php [L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+myfolder/([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (?!^myfolder/)^(.*)$ /myfolder/$1 [L,NC]    

### Remove userprofile?user= ### ( Not working - 500 error of all page )
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+userprofile\?user=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ userprofile?user=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Sir, I already ask "I want to remove userprofile?user= from userprofile?user=myname" Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have it this way:

**root .htaccess**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+myfolder/userprofile\?user=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+myfolder/(\S*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^((?!^myfolder/).*)$ /myfolder/$1 [L,NC]
```

**/myfolder/.htaccess:**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /myfolder/

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ userprofile?user=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thank u sir. But not work. show: a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: error page current url is:- http://myweb.com/myname/?user=myname

Comment: Sir, I can't find any thing on all error logs. update also not work. I want it: http://domain.com/myname. Here I have a folder also like http://domain.com/myfolder/userprofile?user=myname. myfolder hidden also by htaccess with your htaccess rule (my previous post)

Comment: Sir I update my question. htaccess at root directory

Comment: Sir. not working also

Comment: Sorry sir. In first rule my profile page url show: myweb.com/myname/?user=myname which 500 error. And 2nd rule have no change.

Comment: You must enter: `http://domain.com/name` in your browser to test this. Make sure to test in a new browser and have .htaccess exactly as shown above. I have already tested this code and it works in my apache.

Comment: Sir, its show a slash/ after name if I use my name "koc" or "admin", that is domain.com/koc . I have also a admin and koc folder on myfolder and root directory. which I rename admindir and kocdir, but not work also.

Comment: If `admin` is a directory then a trailing will indeed be added by `mod_dir` module not by these rules. Just try with `http://domain.com/name` where `name` is not a directory. Thanks