# How can hide a folder name and userprofile.php?user= by htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

In my web `root`, my pages are:

index.php,
  about.php,
  header.php,
  footer.php,
  contact.php,
  .htaccess

And in `login` folder

register.php,
  main.php,
  userprofile.php,
  .htaccess

Root pages display url: www.myweb.com/about

And `login` folder pages display 
url: 
www.myweb.com/login/main
www.myweb.com/login/userprofile.php?user=myname

Now how can I hide `login` and `userprofile.php?user=` from address bar by .htaccess.
I want to display `login` folder pages url like: www.myweb.com/main, www.myweb.com/myname

Comment: What is the URL you want to display in browser?

Comment: Update what i want to display. Thank you sir.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove userprofile?user=myname by htacces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28515342/remove-userprofileuser-myname-by-htacces)

Comment: @koc: What should happen if `main.php` also exists in root directory? In that case `www.myweb.com/myname` might become ambiguous

Comment: @ anubhava: If I use my previous post rule by you, I can't open my home page index.php file that mean www.myweb.com otherwise that work well for all others page. It's display:" You don't have permission to access /login/ on this server.  404 Not Found error.."

Comment: @ anubhava: As par you said, I remove my login folder. Now I just want to remove "userprofile.php?user=" , that means It's display like www.myweb.com/username  thank you.